# Django Rest Framework serializers allow dotted notation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, form-data

I'm using Django 1.11 and Django Rest Framework to make an REST API.

I have models as:

```
class Product(models.Model):
...

class Image(models.Model):
   product = ForeignKey(Product)
```

when i'm creating a POST request to create new product ( `Content-Type: multipart\form-data]`) i have to use the notation:

`images[0]image` : `<SOME_IMAGE_FILE>`
`images[1]image` : `<SOME_IMAGE_FILE>`

Is there a way to use a dotted notation like:

`images.0.image` : `<SOME_IMAGE_FILE>`
`images.1.image` : `<SOME_IMAGE_FILE>`

Should i create a custom parser ( http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/ ) ?